# how to get listbox selected items tag in mainpage xaml

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am developing windows phone 8 app.I need a user response in some part of my application 
i create windows phone user control page .User will select a value from a listbox that is in usercontrol page

here is code of my user control page

```
<Grid x:Name="columngrid"  Background="#FF1FCB4E" Width="480"  >        
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Name="URLListBox" Grid.Row="0"  Background="#FF1FCB4E"  >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF0B232F" BorderThickness="2">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="surename" Width="460" Tag="{Binding b1Tag}" Height="80"  FontSize="25" Text="{Binding text}"   Foreground="#FFBF9595" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" />
                </Border>                                      
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="btnOK"  Content="OK" Background="#FF892121" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2"  x:Name="btnCancel"  Content="Cancel" Background="#FF892121"/>            
</Grid>
```

i want to get selected textblock's text in mainpage.xaml.But When i create class object for user control page i cant reach textblock.I can only reach listbox.How can i get selected textblock's text
I try this but i realized that s will bring listbox object

```
        surah popupsurah = new surah();//usercontrol page
        Popup popup2 = new Popup();
        private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            collapsedgrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            popupsurah.URLListBox.Tap += (s, args) => 
            {
                string transferID = ((TextBlock)s).Text as string;
```

Comment: here is a sample help you out http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-expose-properties-of-a-user-control-in-windows-phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to do binding with the ListBox SelectedItem property and so you can easily retrieve it from the object itself.

Something like below,(Algorithm)

You can have a class:

```
class MyClass
{
List<string> Items{get;set;}
string SelectedItem{get;set;}
}
```

You can pass an instance of this class to the UserControl:

```
MyUserControl(MyClass);
```

In the Constructor of MyUserControl:

set the DataContext: this.DataContext=MyClass;

Bind the Property Names in the xaml. Thats it.

Another approach is:

Save the selected Item string into the state dictionary:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["SelectedItem"]=YourSelectedItemString;
```

You can retrieve in the MainPage.xaml like this:

```
var selectedItem=PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["SelectedItem"] as string;
```

Comment: i have a problem i cant get the text from list box in usercontrolpagexaml.cs

Comment: You can get it from the OnSelectionChanged Event by using ListBoxName.SelectedItem or ListBoxName.SelectedIndex; If you are Binding ItemsSource Property of ListBox then you have to TypeCast your SelectedItem as: ListBoxName.SelectedItem as ViewModelType;

Answer (score 0):

Better you can go for Phone:LongListSelector control which is more optimised than ListBox,Which has almost all events and properties of ListBox.